# Copy an array to linked List in each data field

Tags: c, arrays, linked-list, character, singly-linked-list

First, sorry if my question has already been answered. I found some threads that are (in a way) similiar but I was not able to solve my problem.
Second, I am new to single-linked-list in C so I would be happy if you could answer my question as easy as possible.

I made a simple linke-list, that has characters in it:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h> 

// declaration of node
struct _Node_ 
{
char data_string;
struct _Node_ *next;
};
int main() {
//a simple linked list with 3 Nodes, Create Nodes
struct _Node_* head = NULL; 
struct _Node_* second = NULL; 
struct _Node_* third = NULL;

//allocate 3 Nodes in the heap
head = (struct _Node_*)malloc(sizeof(struct _Node_));  
second = (struct _Node_*)malloc(sizeof(struct _Node_)); 
third = (struct _Node_*)malloc(sizeof(struct _Node_)); 

// assign data for head
head->data_string = 'H';      //assign value according struct
head->next = second;          //points to the next node

// assign data for second
second->data_string = 'E';
second->next = third;

third->data_string = 'Y';
third->next = NULL;

return 0;
}
```

The linked list does now look like this:

```
 /* Linked list _Node_

       head         second           third
         |            |                |
         |            |                |
    +---+---+     +---+---+       +----+------+ 
    | 1 | o-----> |  2| o-------> |  3 | NULL | 
    +---+---+     +---+---+       +----+------+        

  */
```

Let's assume I have 3 arrays with the following:

```
char name1[] = "Joe";
char name2[] = "Eve";
char name3[] = "Brad";
```

And my goal is to copy this array into each data field, so the result looks like this:

```
 /* Linked list _Node_

       head            second              third
         |               |                   |
         |               |                   |
    +-----+---+     +-------+---+     +-------+------+ 
    | Joe | o-----> |  Eve  | o-----> |  Brad | NULL | 
    +-----+---+     +-------+---+     +-------+------+        

  */
```

How can I achieve this? I already tried adding/changing the following:

```
...

struct _Node_ 
{
char data_string[8];
struct _Node_ *next;
};    

...

...

char name1[] = "Joe";
char name2[] = "Eve";
char name3[] = "Brad";

// assign data for head
head->data_string = name1;      //assign value according struct
head->next = second;          //points to the next node

// assign data for second
second->data_string = name2;
second->next = third;

third->data_string = name3;
third->next = NULL;

...
```

But all I get after compiling is:

```
stack_overflow.c:27:23: error: array type 'char [8]' is not assignable
head->data_string = name1;      //assign value according struct
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ ^
stack_overflow.c:31:25: error: array type 'char [8]' is not assignable
second->data_string = name2;
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ ^
stack_overflow.c:34:24: error: array type 'char [8]' is not assignable
third->data_string = name3;
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ ^
3 errors generated.
```

Maybe someone could help, I appreciate any help.
Again, sorry if this is a duplicate but I am not able to solve this with other threads..

Comment: Make it a `char *data_string` and allocate memory for it with `malloc` and use `strcpy` to copy the string to the allocated memory.

Comment: Note: you assigning does _not_ copy the data. So `head->data_string = name1;` is wrong. Use `strcpy(head->data_string, name1);`

Comment: the problem is that /*char data_string;*/ it holds only one char- bad name. if you want it to point to a string you can use char* str - and set it to point to an outer set string or allocate the memory for that string after you init the node according to its length. you can also make the char var an array of a set capacity char string[10] or example- but it will fit names shorter or equal to 9, and you waist memory on the shorter names.

Comment: ok i changed `char data_string[8];`to `char *data_string;`, then i changed every name-array from `head->data_string = name1;` to `strcpy(head->data_string, name1);`
Where do I have to put the `malloc` declaration in?

Comment: @PaulOgilvie could you maybe give me a code example? I think I am using malloc wrong, I get Segmentation Fault..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You asked for a code example:

```
struct Node 
{
    char *data_string;
    struct Node *next;
};

struct Node *newNode (char *s)
{
    struct Node *node;
    if (!s) return 0; // error: no string
    if (!(node= malloc(sizeof(struct Node)))) return 0; // no more memory
    node->data_string= malloc(strlen(s)+1);
    if (!node->data_string) {
        free(node);
        return 0;
    }
    strcpy(node->data_string,s);
    node->next= 0;
    return(node);
}
void freeNode(struct Node *node)
{
    if (!node) return;
    if (node->data_string) free(node->data_string);
    free(node);
}
```

Notes:

- you alocate the memory for the string 1 more than the length because a string in C has a null terminating character.
- do not use underscores before an identifier name - those are reserved for the compiler.
- do not cast the result of `malloc`. It returns a `void` pointer, which is compatible with any pointer type.
- this example includes all required error checking.