# How to delete a string in an array in C

Tags: arrays, c, string

I am trying to delete a string (name) from an array using the below code.
`AddArray` is to get an array from the user and `RemoveArray` is to delete the string

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define LENGTH 5
unsigned char num = 0;
unsigned char numact = 0;
#include <string.h>
#define STR_MAX_SIZE 255
#define Names 5
#define Groups 5

void AddArray() {
  int i = 0;
  char word[Names][30] = {""};
  char word2[Groups][50] = {""};
  for (i = 0; i < Names; i++) {
    printf("--Input Name = ");
    if (!fgets(word[i], sizeof word[i], stdin))
      break;
    size_t len = strlen(word[i]);
    if (word[i][len - 1] == '\n')
      word[i][--len] = 0;
    printf("--Input Group = ");
    if (!fgets(word2[i], sizeof word2[i], stdin))
      break;
    size_t len2 = strlen(word2[i]);
    if (word2[i][len2 - 1] == '\n')
      word2[i][--len2] = 0;
  }
  putchar('\n');
}

void RemoveArray() {
  int position, i = 0, n = 5;
  char word[Names][30];
  char word2[Groups][50];
  printf("Enter the location where you wish to delete name\n");
  scanf("%d", &position);
  if (position >= n + 1)
    printf("Deletion not possible.\n");
  else
  {
    for (i = position - 1; i < n - 1; i++)
    {
      word[Names][i] == word[Names][i + 1];
      word2[Groups][i] == word2[Groups][i + 1];
      printf("Resultant array:\n");
      for (i = 0; i < n - 1; i++)
        printf("%d, %s, %s\n", i, word[i], word2[i]);
    }
  }
}
```

However, for some reason,

```
word[Names][i] == word[Names][i+1];
word2[Groups][i] == word2[Groups][i+1];
```

is not working (probably this is doing nothing), and my results only deletes the last string because of `for (i = position - 1; i < n - 1; i++)`

How can I delete a string from an array in C?

Comment: You should use [`strcmp()`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strcmp.3.html) for comparision of C strings.

Comment: `word[Names][i] == word[Names][i+1]; word2[Groups][i] == word2[Groups][i+1];` does nothing. The result of comparisions are simply discarded without being used. You will have to put comparisions in conditions of branch statements such as `if`, `for`, `while`.

Comment: @MikeCAT How can I use branch statements to delete a string?

Comment: Also you will have to put strings to be deleted to the array first.

Comment: @MikeCAT I have edited the question for showing how the string was added

Comment: Linked list (over array) is better suited to delete and add objects.  An array element element can be made to contain `\0`, but it will still remain in memory.

Comment: What are added in `AddArray` are discarded on returning from that and nothing are added to the arrays in `RemoveArray`.

Comment: Either add `if (len2 && word2[i][len2 - 1] == '\n')`, to prevent *UB* if the user cancels input or, replace your entire block to trim `\n'` with `word2[i][strcspn (word2[i], "\n")] = 0;` which is a much more robust method that will handle empty and non-empty strings alike. (same thing for the `word[i]` trim as well)

Comment: `char word[Names][30] = {""};` and `char word2[Groups][50] = {""};` are both local to the `AddArray()` function and therefor do not survive after the return of the function. You need to pass the arrays as parameters to the function.

Answer (score 0):

> *"However, for some reason,... is not working"*

```
word[Names][i] == word[Names][i+1];
word2[Groups][i] == word2[Groups][i+1];
```

Strings in C can be compared using [strcmp()](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_strcmp.htm).  For example:

```
if(strcmp(word[Names][i], word[Names][i+1]) == 0);
if(strcmp(word2[Groups][i], word2[Groups][i+1]) == 0);
```

> *"How can I delete a string from an array in C?"*

This is likely not possible in the way you are proposing.
For example, to delete a string from an array of strings means to delete all character content from that area of memory.  i.e. either setting the first character of the string to `NULL`, or memset() the entire array element to `NULL`, eg:   `memset(array, 0, sizeof array);`.   Because passing a `null` string to printf will invoke [undefined behavior](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/g-fact-44-passing-null-to-printf-in-c/), this approach will not work.
For example, the following code may appear to work, but it may also do something [completely unexpected](http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/N/nasal-demons.html):

```
int main(void)
{
    char strings[3][20] = {"first string", "second string", "third string"};
    //delete second string
    strings[1][0] = 0;//this will be passed to printf as a null string
    printf("First string: %s\nSecond string: %s\nThird string: %s", strings[0], strings[1], strings[2]);
    
    return 0;
}
```

If you really want to delete a string from a collection of strings [linked lists](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/linked-list-set-1-introduction/) are the way to go.  Some steps (with links) to do this follow:

- [Copy your array to a linked lis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53813720/copy-an-array-to-linked-list-in-each-data-fieldt)
- [Search linked list for either matching string. (or index of node)](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/search-an-element-in-a-linked-list-iterative-and-recursive/)
- [Delete node containing string](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/linked-list-set-3-deleting-node/?ref=lbp) ([or index](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/delete-a-linked-list-node-at-a-given-position/?ref=lbp))

Comment: If I understand the question, then using `strcpy()` or  `memcpy()` of `length+1` chars to copy the string in the row below over the current and then setting the last row that would move up starting char to the nul-terminating char to make it an empty-string should do.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin - Yes possible, but not viable or rational.  I would never recommend that approach (nor do I believe you would either.) even for a 2 element array, let alone one with 100s or 1000s of elements.

Comment: Well yes, for a learning exercise, that is exactly what I was recommending. Would I want to recommend copying large numbers of rows within fixed arrays in production code, of course not. But for learning how to think though validly using a block of memory, input validation and bounds protection -- it's a really good exercise. And for a few hundred rows, even on a microcontroller -- you would be hard pressed to notice any delay. So I agree with you from a production code standpoint, but disagree from a learning exercise standpoint.

Answer (score 0):

This way of managing strings is hard. Because you use statically allocated arrays, so it is a primitice way comparing to modern programming approaches. You better use dynamic memory allocation and pointers to be able to add and remove tuples or rows to the list. Also you can implement a LinkedList structure since it is easy to manage nodes but a little difficult to implement.
But if you insist to make it in this primitive way, then you'll have to delete a row of string character by character and use some row count for the list and row availability flags for each row.

Answer (score 0):

With two 2D arrays both with automatic storage duration, you have two fixed blocks of memory that must remain valid during the operation of your program. You cannot declare the arrays within the functions you call, because the storage for the arrays will no longer be valid after the function returns. (the storage will be created within memory used to set up the function call, the function stack frame, and that memory will be released for re-use on the function return) Instead you will need to declare your arrays in `main()` and pass the arrays as parameters to the functions that need them.

As far as whether you can use 2D arrays and then add and remove strings -- of course you can. The arrays are simply blocks of memory you can make any valid use of that you desire. To add to the arrays, you simply need to check if they are already full by passing the number of elements contained in the arrays as an additional parameter to your functions (pass a pointer so that you can update the value at that address in the function and have the change visible back in the calling function -- or return the updated value and assign it back in the caller)

Now you wouldn't want to use this approach on large data sets as copying up to your arrays size worth or rows for each removal is highly inefficient. However for use as a learning exercise with less than a few hundred rows of so, it's just fine. It doesn't matter if the arrays have automatic storage duration or are created with allocated storage duration, manipulating what is in the blocks of memory is largely the same. Validate and protect the bounds of whatever memory you are working with.

To remove from the arrays, you simply check whether the index to remove is a valid index and it is within the elements that are currently stored. If so, just copy each of the rows above down by one and update the number of elements stored accordingly. The arrays are just storage, there for you to use.

Before looking at how you can do this, let's look at your defines. Generally macros names are defined in all upper case. You don't need nearly as many as you have (unless you are using them for reasons not shown). You can fix the case and narrow them down to what is needed similar to the following:

```
#define NROWS       5       /* simplify your constants */
#define MAXLEN     32       /*     all upper-case      */
#define LINLEN   1024
```

While not an error, C generally avoids the use of `camelCase` or `MixedCase` variable and function names in favor of all *lower-case*. That is a matter of style, so completely up to you.

Your `addarray()` function could be written similar to the following:

```
int addarray (char (*names)[MAXLEN], char (*groups)[MAXLEN], size_t *nmemb)
{
    if (*nmemb == NROWS) {                                  /* check array full */
        puts ("\n(arrays full)\n");
        return 0;
    }
    
    char line[LINLEN];                                      /* buffer to hold input */
    size_t len;                                             /* length of input */
    
    fputs ("\n--Input Name  = ", stdout);                   /* prompt for name */
    if (!fgets (line, LINLEN, stdin) || *line == '\n') {    /* VALIDATE!, handle EOF */
        puts ("\n(user canceled input)\n");
        return 0;
    }
    line[(len = strcspn(line, "\n"))] = 0;                  /* trim \n, save length */
    
    if (len >= MAXLEN) {                                    /* validate name fits */
        fputs ("  error: name exceeds storage\n", stderr);
        return 0;
    }
    
    memcpy (names[*nmemb], line, len + 1);                  /* copy to names */
    
    fputs ("--Input Group = ", stdout);                     /* prompt for group */
    if (!fgets (line, LINLEN, stdin) || *line == '\n') {    /* VALIDATE!, handle EOF */
        puts ("\n(user canceled input)\n");
        return 0;
    }
    line[(len = strcspn(line, "\n"))] = 0;                  /* trim \n, save length */
    
    if (len >= MAXLEN) {                                    /* validate name fits */
        fputs ("  error: group exceeds storage\n", stderr);
        return 0;
    }
    
    memcpy (groups[(*nmemb)++], line, len + 1);             /* copy to groups,
                                                             * increment nmemb */
    return 1;       /* return success */
}
```

(**note:** most of the function is simply validation. You must validate all input and ensure your do not attempt to write beyond your array bounds)

The `removearray()` is a bit shorter due to there being only one input validations. You could write your function similar to:

```
int removearray (char (*names)[MAXLEN], char (*groups)[MAXLEN], size_t *nmemb)
{
    size_t loc, i;
    char line[LINLEN];                                      /* buffer to hold input */
    
    fputs ("enter location to remove: ", stdout);           /* request idx to remove */
    if (!fgets (line, LINLEN, stdin) || *line == '\n') {    /* VALIDATE!, handle EOF */
        puts ("\n(user canceled input)\n");
        return 0;
    }
    if (sscanf (line, "%zu", &loc) != 1) {                  /* convert/VALIDATE! */
        fputs ("  error: invalid location input.\n", stderr);
        return 0;
    }

    if (NROWS - 1 < loc || *nmemb <= loc) {                 /* validate location */
        fputs ("  error: position requested out of range.\n", stderr);
        return 0;
    }
    
    for (i = loc + 1; i < *nmemb; i++) {        /* loop from index above until end */
        strcpy (names[i - 1], names[i]);        /* overwrite row to remove */
        strcpy (groups[i - 1], groups[i]);      /* ditto */
    }
    (*nmemb)--;                                 /* decrement no. of members in array */
    
    return 1;       /* return success */
}
```

Then to ensure your array storage remains valid, declare them within `main()`. That way you are free to pass the arrays to any function where they are needed along with a variable (or pointer) tracking the number of elements within them. A short implementation would be:

```
int main (void) {
    
    char names[NROWS][MAXLEN] = {""},                       /* names */
        groups[NROWS][MAXLEN] = {""};                       /* groups */
    size_t nmemb = 0;                                       /* no. members in each */
    
    while (addarray (names, groups, &nmemb)) {}             /* add to both */
    prnarrays (names, groups, nmemb);                       /* output both */
    putchar ('\n');
    
    while (removearray (names, groups, &nmemb)) {}          /* remove from both */
    prnarrays (names, groups, nmemb);                       /* output both */
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

Exercising the code you could do the following (just press <kbd>Enter</kbd> alone on a blank line when done with either input to stop input at that point):

```
$ ./bin/array_addrem_row

--Input Name  = my
--Input Group = pronoun

--Input Name  = dog
--Input Group = animal

--Input Name  = has
--Input Group = being-verb

--Input Name  = fleas
--Input Group = insect

--Input Name  = bummer!
--Input Group = adverb

(arrays full)

my                    pronoun
dog                   animal
has                   being-verb
fleas                 insect
bummer!               adverb

enter location to remove: 4
enter location to remove: 0
enter location to remove:

(user canceled input)

dog                   animal
has                   being-verb
fleas                 insect
```

or, simply repeatedly removing the first row until your arrays are empty, you could do:

```
$ ./bin/array_addrem_row

--Input Name  = my
--Input Group = pronoun

--Input Name  = dog
--Input Group = animal

--Input Name  = has
--Input Group = being-verb

--Input Name  = fleas
--Input Group = insect

--Input Name  = bummer!
--Input Group = adverb

(arrays full)

my                    pronoun
dog                   animal
has                   being-verb
fleas                 insect
bummer!               adverb

enter location to remove: 0
enter location to remove: 0
enter location to remove: 0
enter location to remove: 0
enter location to remove: 0
enter location to remove: 0
  error: position requested out of range.

(arrays empty)
```

It is just arithmetic that is needed to keep your array operations within bounds and valid. The complete code including the `prnarrays()` function is as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define NROWS       5       /* simplify your constants */
#define MAXLEN     32       /*     all upper-case      */
#define LINLEN   1024

int addarray (char (*names)[MAXLEN], char (*groups)[MAXLEN], size_t *nmemb)
{
    if (*nmemb == NROWS) {                                  /* check array full */
        puts ("\n(arrays full)\n");
        return 0;
    }
    
    char line[LINLEN];                                      /* buffer to hold input */
    size_t len;                                             /* length of input */
    
    fputs ("\n--Input Name  = ", stdout);                   /* prompt for name */
    if (!fgets (line, LINLEN, stdin) || *line == '\n') {    /* VALIDATE!, handle EOF */
        puts ("\n(user canceled input)\n");
        return 0;
    }
    line[(len = strcspn(line, "\n"))] = 0;                  /* trim \n, save length */
    
    if (len >= MAXLEN) {                                    /* validate name fits */
        fputs ("  error: name exceeds storage\n", stderr);
        return 0;
    }
    
    memcpy (names[*nmemb], line, len + 1);                  /* copy to names */
    
    fputs ("--Input Group = ", stdout);                     /* prompt for group */
    if (!fgets (line, LINLEN, stdin) || *line == '\n') {    /* VALIDATE!, handle EOF */
        puts ("\n(user canceled input)\n");
        return 0;
    }
    line[(len = strcspn(line, "\n"))] = 0;                  /* trim \n, save length */
    
    if (len >= MAXLEN) {                                    /* validate name fits */
        fputs ("  error: group exceeds storage\n", stderr);
        return 0;
    }
    
    memcpy (groups[(*nmemb)++], line, len + 1);             /* copy to groups,
                                                             * increment nmemb */
    return 1;       /* return success */
}

int removearray (char (*names)[MAXLEN], char (*groups)[MAXLEN], size_t *nmemb)
{
    size_t loc, i;
    char line[LINLEN];                                      /* buffer to hold input */
    
    fputs ("enter location to remove: ", stdout);           /* request idx to remove */
    if (!fgets (line, LINLEN, stdin) || *line == '\n') {    /* VALIDATE!, handle EOF */
        puts ("\n(user canceled input)\n");
        return 0;
    }
    if (sscanf (line, "%zu", &loc) != 1) {                  /* convert/VALIDATE! */
        fputs ("  error: invalid location input.\n", stderr);
        return 0;
    }

    if (NROWS - 1 < loc || *nmemb <= loc) {                 /* validate location */
        fputs ("  error: position requested out of range.\n", stderr);
        return 0;
    }
    
    for (i = loc + 1; i < *nmemb; i++) {        /* loop from index above until end */
        strcpy (names[i - 1], names[i]);        /* overwrite row to remove */
        strcpy (groups[i - 1], groups[i]);      /* ditto */
    }
    (*nmemb)--;                                 /* decrement no. of members in array */
    
    return 1;       /* return success */
}

void prnarrays (char (*names)[MAXLEN], char (*groups)[MAXLEN], size_t nmemb)
{
    if (nmemb == 0) {
        puts ("\n(arrays empty)\n");
        return;
    }
    
    for (size_t i = 0; i < nmemb; i++)
        printf ("%-20s  %s\n", names[i], groups[i]);
}

int main (void) {
    
    char names[NROWS][MAXLEN] = {""},                       /* names */
        groups[NROWS][MAXLEN] = {""};                       /* groups */
    size_t nmemb = 0;                                       /* no. members in each */
    
    while (addarray (names, groups, &nmemb)) {}             /* add to both */
    prnarrays (names, groups, nmemb);                       /* output both */
    putchar ('\n');
    
    while (removearray (names, groups, &nmemb)) {}          /* remove from both */
    prnarrays (names, groups, nmemb);                       /* output both */
}
```

Look things over and let me know if you have any questions.